# Run 2 instance of Microsoft unified service desk on a same machine

Tags: dynamics-crm, unified-service-desk

I am facing a problem and not much support is available on internet regarding this.

I want to run 2 instance of Microsoft Unified Service desk on a same machine.

I don't know how to do it and it is quite critical. Also, there is a simulator running with it which is using port 5555. The other problem is how can i change the port of simulator for 2nd instance.
Like i have a simulator running for port 5555 and i would like to run it for port 5556 or any other to run the 2nd instance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a 2nd instance of USD by copying the USD client folder and running it from the copied folder.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM USD\USD => copy to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM USD\USD2nd

Run 1st from original USD and the 2nd from copy USD2nd.

I do this for testing CTI calls to and from USD.

Changing the port I have no idea about.